# sql "group by" to group rows corresponding to same pair

Tags: sql

I have a table with 2 columns - "primary" and "secondary".  In addition there are other columns too.
Following is a sample set of rows:

```
id=1, primary=A, secondary=B, .....
id=2, primary=C, secondary=D, .....
....
.......
id=200, primary=B, secondary=A, .....
id=300, primary=J, secondary=D, .....
```

I need a "GROUP BY" query that will group all rows for which the primary and secondary values belong to same pair of values **regardless of the order**.
So,
groups should look as follows:

```
group=1, nodepair=BA, ....   // (primary=A && secondary=B) OR (primary=B && secondary=A)
group=2, nodepair=JM, ....   // (primary=J && secondary=M) OR (primary=M && secondary=J)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select least(primary, secondary)
      ,greatest(primary, secondary)
 from yourtable
group 
   by least(primary, secondary)
     ,greatest(primary, secondary);
```

It will give you one group per unique combination of Primary/Secondary regardless of the order, i.e {A,B} is the same as {B,A}.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table t1
inner join table t2
on t1.primary = t2.secondary 
and t1.secondary = t2.primary
```

Then you'll have in result:

id=1, primary=A, secondary=B, id=200, primary=B, secondary=A
id=200, primary=B, secondary=A, id=1, primary=A, secondary=B