# Group rows based on similar paired values

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table with a data structure that looks like so:

```
a,b
1,2
2,1
3,1
```

What I would like to do is group these 3 rows into 2 rows based on the 2 values a and b if the combination resides in either row together into 1 row so I can do a count query. I'd like to get a result set similar to:

```
a,b,count
1,2,2
3,1,1
```

Comment: Can you please show the table structure and what you have done thus far?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: No, you did not ask a straightforward question. You asked a very unclear question. Your edited version is better, but I still couldn't make any sense of it until I read the answer mu posted. If you can't accept criticism of this nature, then SO may not be for you.

Comment: Anybody could have asked further clarification to what I meant rather than downvote bashing and voting to close without a comment.

Comment: No one is obligated to donate their time asking for clarification. We receive a *flood* of poorly written questions all day every day. Most askers never respond to requests to clarification anyway. Downvoting and close voting are both appropriate and reasonable responses. Anything more is 100% pure generosity and is not required, and you certainly shouldn't demand more or complain when you don't receive more.

Comment: I still believe it's rather straight forward, but can you recommend a better way I could word this question so people trying to find the same answer can properly find this? I searched for a long time before turning to stack overflow. It's a complex question don't get me wrong, but I fail to see how I could change the wording to add more clarity to the question I've posed.

Comment: That said, you're right and I'm sorry. It just feels really bad to be voted to close on an issue I genuinely felt was informative. At this point I'd really love to make it the best possible question for anybody in my boat to find.

Comment: Hi. Your question *does not say what output you want for given input*. And your two "possible solutions" are also unclear. Use enough sentences, phrases & words, including references to relevant parts or combinations of things, to say what you mean. Read what you wrote: it is *not clear*. Clear writing requires effort & redrafts. PS You have no reason to (mis)interpret down & close votes as you are. Read [help] links & google how things work with '(meta.stackexchange.com OR meta.stackoverflow.com)'. The downvote arrow mouseover text says, fails in one or more of research, utility or clarity.

Comment: Eg: "group these 2 rows into 1 row": Which two rows? Or do you mean "these rows with the numeral '2' in them"? Group into 1 row??--OK, that's reasonable, you mean group certain rows into a group for which you want to calculate the ... then ... then .... Or do you want to group rows per a certain property then ....? "based on the 2 values together": OK, *based on 2 things* but *how exactly*? And "together" adds nothing--could it be based on them but *not* together? You are just using vague phrases consistent with something but not *saying* it. "into 1 row": Already said that--typo? Etc.

Comment: Hi. Couldn't you just say that you want to group rows by the value of the set {a, b} or table ((a), (b)) & then select count(\*)? Your edited text is still unclear with "based on" & "together" useless & "the combination" unclear--*what* combination?--combined *how*? You are still not making yourself *say* what you want. If we didn't have or create type "set" or "table" we could still say, group into groups of rows with the same a value & the same b value. That phrasing didn't come to me quickly either, I have had many false starts. (Also I only know what you want (?) from the accepted answer.)

Comment: PS So now to bring the title up to date/scratch: Maybe 'group rows that have the same pair of values regardless of column'. And now... googling this with 'sql stackoverflow'... a bunch of hits of which the first for me is an *exact duplicate*. [sql “group by” to group rows corresponding to same pair](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15241120/3404097) I would now vote to close your question as a duplicate but I already used my close vote for "unclear". (Which I would have removed when this question got clear.) (Even more hits putting '(unordered)' in front of 'pair' in the title suggestion/search.)

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`greatest` and `least`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) to get the pair of columns in a consistent order:

```
select count(*)
from things
group by greatest(a, b), least(a, b)
```

That will give you the `2` you're looking for.

Comment: Wow, what a great idea! Thanks, this really adds clarity to the issue I've been having. I'm going to wait for a little bit before I mark this as accepted in case there is an answer more straight forward.